# Machista está para homem tal como _______ está para rico

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

Que termo se usa para caracterizar alguém que discrimina em virtude da capacidade económica ou status social?

Da mesma maneira que o machista descrimina em função do sexo.

Comment: [snobe](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/snobe) (esnobe pt-BR)?

Comment: acho que esnobe não tem a ver com ser ou não rico. Pode-se ser pobre e mesmo assim, esnobar os outros.

Comment: Pergunta interessante, mas o homem machista não se limita a achar-se superior, que é um um bocado vago: pode defender que as mulheres não deveriam ter acesso a certas profissões ou cargos, ou que o lugar delas é na cozinha, ou que um homem casado pode ter amantes, mas a mulher não. Poderias melhorar a pergunta explicando melhor quais são as atitudes de "riquista" que tu tens em mente. É simplesmente, eu sou melhor que tu porque sou rico; só quem paga mais de X em imposto de rendimento é que deveria ter direito de voto; a educação e saúde deveriam ser pagas, quem não tem dinheiro que se lixe?

Comment: Não entendo, não podem haver mulheres com atitudes machistas? Quero dizer aquele que nega a igualdade de direitos e deveres entre os gêneros? Então se machismo só esta para homens, significa ou que o seu texto esta indicando uma situação especifica do qual não foi informado na pergunta, ou simplesmente a pergunta não faz sentido (acaso for uma prova).

Comment: Chamam pessoa metida a ricas de burguês.

Comment: @AndréLyra depende do contexto, a pergunta não apresenta um contexto certo, burguês creio que no popular indique aquele que goza de certos privilégios, ou que se preocupa em acumular bens. Machismo é uma palavra que indica discriminação, logo ser burgues não é necessariamente uma discriminação contra alguém mais desfavorecido, então a palavra provavelmente que o autor da pergunta (AP) procura é uma que equipare a discriminação especifica. Logo creio que sem contexto especifico na pergunta é quase impossível responde-la e o melhor seja fecha-la até que o autor edite e dê detalhes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento há mulheres machistas, como pode haver «_____»s pobres. Uma mulher que discrimina outra por gostar de desporto e não saber cozinhar, pode ser machista. Um pobre que discrimine outro por andar feliz e sentir-se realizado apesar de ser um zé-ninguém e não ter dinheiro "nem para mandar tocar um cego", pode ser «______». Acho que a pergunta não cai nesse erro; mas se achas que sim, edita-a para ficar melhor. :)

Comment: @ANeves eu acho que não entendeu bem o que eu quis dizer, ou eu não soube me explicar, o que estou querendo dizer é que a pergunta esta ampla ou não clara, não esta de todo mal, mas ela causa alguma confusão de entendimento, ainda mais se tiver orientação politica, o que levaria a baseado em opiniões, veja bem, o que estou querendo dizer é que se o foco for politico então este não é o site para se perguntar este tipo de coisa, talvez caberia uma comunidade sobre filosofia ou politica, mas não de português...

Comment: ... Não estou contestando visões politicas especificas, o problema é que é um site sobre Português, consegue entender? Se o autor afirmar um "contexto" pra pergunta dá pra até ter alguma maneira de responder a pergunta, mas da maneira que esta me soa como tendo diferentes possibilidades de responder.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ah, desculpa, acho que agora sim percebo melhor, tens as mesmas reservas que o Jacinto: que era preciso «explicar melhor quais são as atitudes de "riquista" que [o perguntador] tem em mente». Certo? Concordo, têm razão nisso.

Comment: @ANeves sim, entendeu perfeitamente.

Comment: @Jacinto eu editei a pergunta não sei se antes ou depois do seu comentário. Não há um contexto preciso, da mesma forma que não se utiliza a palavra "racista" para quem descrimina em função da raça apenas para a utilização de serviços públicos ou da liberdade, mas sim para qualquer situação em que a discriminação seja motivada pela raça.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento 
Idem.
No caso do machista, a palavra utiliza-se para qualquer discriminação fundamentada pelo sexo (feminino) e não em situações específicas: «pode defender que as mulheres não deveriam ter acesso a certas profissões ou cargos, ou que o lugar delas é na cozinha, ou que um homem casado pode ter amantes, mas a mulher não». Aplica-se em todos os casos.
Isto para dizer que não percebi cabalmente as vossas críticas, mas obviamente que ainda posso melhorar a pergunta se as perceber.
Ou então, a pergunta já ficou corrigida com as alterações que fiz entretanto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da maneira que a pergunta foi feita qualquer muitos termos serviriam para completar o "espaço" da frase, quero dizer, creio que machismo não precisa ser exclusivo para homens, já que o machismo seria uma atitude aonde se nega a igualdade de direitos e deveres entre os gêneros, entendo que a diferença é que no machismo a discriminação seja contra as mulheres e no sexismo seja contra gênero ou orientação sexual.

Visando isto a pergunta me soa um pouco vaga e espero que realmente não seja uma pergunta com fundamento político ou filosófico, mas sim de Português, porque este penso ser o foco da comunidade.

Então o que consegui entender da pergunta é que machismo sendo uma discriminação contra o gênero feminino, ele valorizaria o gênero masculino, então *«homem»* na sua frase talvez se refira ao gênero, sem um contexto a palavra *«rico»* poderia ser completada provavelmente com diferentes termos.

No entanto se situação é especificamente aonde valoriza o *«rico»* e inferioriza o *«pobre»*, no caso as palavras já citadas parecem não se encaixar tão bem no possível contexto da sua pergunta:

- [**esnobe <sup>(priberam)</sup>**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/esnobe): Que ou quem mostra superioridade, arrogância e afectação.
- [**classista <sup>(priberam)</sup>**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/classista): Que ou quem representa ou defende os interesses de uma classe.

Ou seja, em nenhuma das palavras inferioriza ou indica descriminalização de uma condição financeira, então procurei aonde pude, jornais e websites sobre noticias que falavam de discriminação contra pessoas por situação econômica, o único termo que encontrei que indica diretamente esta situação foi:

> Discriminação social

Answer (score 3):

Se me permite um neologismo (ou um estrangeirismo, visto que é usado no espanhol), temos **aporofóbico** (do grego άπορος (á-poros), sem recursos, indigente, pobre; e φόβος, (-fobos), medo).

Fazendo uma tradução livre da [wikipedia em espanhol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aporofobia):

> (...) se refere ao medo da pobreza e de pessoas pobres. É a repugnância e hostilidade antes os pobres, sem recursos ou desemparados (...)

Nota: Não confundir com a *peniafobia*, que é o medo de ficar pobre.

Comment: Tal como homofóbico. Só não considerei a resposta certa por ser um neologismo. Mas um que irei tentar utilizar no futuro.

Comment: Galera tá usando o termo: https://brasil.elpais.com/brasil/2018/08/04/internacional/1533407246_853089.html

Answer (score 2):

A palavra mais adecuado é **classista**, acho eu.  O nível de riqueza que tem alguém é relacionado com a sua classe social, e embora a palavra não refere inherentemente aos ricos, não se usa muito a palavra para referir aos pobres que se sentem superiores aos ricos, como indica a definição no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa:

> que venera ou defende determinadas classes, em especial as classes favorecidas; que defende as diferenças de classe

Não obstante, tem usos mais neutros ou inclusive com sentido que favorece os pobres (sobretudo na política marxista), mas o contexto indicará facilmente o sentido quando o empregamos para referir aos ricos que se sentem superiores.

Comment: Não creio que tenha ouvido *classista* usado com o sentido pretendido, e não é esse o significado dado pelos dicionários. Vê [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/classista) ou [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/classista).

Comment: @Jacinto só faz falta pôr em Google frases de tipo «racista e classista» o «machista e classista» e abundam os exemplos.

Comment: Não obstante, parece que em português tem mais usos neutros que em outras línguas, vou modificar a resposta

Comment: Sim, esta seria a minha resposta preferida, se o significado da palavra fosse esse.

Comment: @FernandoCésarS. incluí a definição do Dicionário da Academia das Ciências onde podes ver a palavra sim significa o que descrevi.

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade, "esnobe" seria a palavra mais precisa pra definir isso. Com o tempo, o sentido foi derivado, mas, originalmente, designava pessoas que, mesmo sem ter título de nobreza, apresentavam desprezo pelas classes inferiores.

Do inglês, "*snob*", do latim ***s***ine **nob**ilitatis (sem nobreza).

Comment: Originalmente, a palavra inglesa *snob* siginificou sapateiro, depois foi termo pejorativo para pessoas de classe baixa, depois pessoa que imita pessoas de classe mais alta. A origem no latim "sine nobilitatis" é invenção (o significado nas primeiras ocorrências conhecidas é sapateiro). De qualquer modo nada disto corresponde ao sentido pretendido. O sentido moderno da palavra é o que mais se aproxima do sentido pretendido--rico que se acha superior por ser rico--mas não é bem, como já observou o Peixoto no comentário acima.

Comment: O [dicionário](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/snobe) também dá uma aceção diferente à palavra: não de discriminar os outros, mas de se julgar superior e altaneiro. É uma distinção pequena mas importante, que acho que invalida a palavra.

Comment: @Jacinto, o _snob_ como "sapateiro" é simplesmente homônimo à abreviação em latim. Eu acho muito complicado fazer uma afirmação tão categórica, como dizer que é invenção, quando claramente **não** há um consenso.

Comment: As fontes que eu consultei são consensuais: *snob* 'esnobe' e *snob* 'sapateiro' são a mesma palavra e não simplesmente homónimos: vê [Oxford learner's dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/snob?q=snob) (clica em "Word Origin"); [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snob) e [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=snob). De qualquer maneira o voto negativo não é meu.

Comment: O voto negativo é meu. Não leves isso a mal, Pedro Alves, que eu gosto de ver gente nova por aqui e espero ver-te noutras perguntas e respostas. Mas acho que a pergunta tem imprecisões que precisam de ser corrigidas: talvez não dizer "seria a mais precisa"; corrigir o que dizes ser o significado de snob (que não bate certo com o do dicionário que eu apresentei) ou alternativamente fundamentá-lo com fontes; e corrigir a origem do significado inglês de "snob" ou alternativamente fundamentá-lo com fontes (para contrapor as fontes do Jacinto).

Comment: As pessoas por aqui às vezes são um bocado sérias (contra mim falo!), mas não ligues muito e vais ver que também somos bem dispostos. :)

Answer (score 1):

Penso que a melhor opção é *elitista*.

Comment: outra opção ilipendiador

Comment: @AndréLyra não conheço essa palavra, você deve estar se referindo ao 
[**«vilipendiador»**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vilipendiador), no entanto se for esta a palavra não creio que tenha o mesmo sentido, consulte a palavra [**«vilipendia»**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vilipendia)

Comment: Que ou aquele que vilipendia; que trata com desprezo.

Comment: @AndréLyra - sim, mas pode-se vilipendiar alguém por ser negro/mulher/judeu/homossexual/torcedor do Palmeiras. Não há nada específico em relação aos pobres na palavra "vilipendiador".

Comment: Pode-se usar palavras que passem a ideia de **desvalorizar alguém** como depreciador ou menosprezador